# Finite State Machine and enclosing

Tags: c#, design-patterns, state

Recently in my work I "forced" to learn to program right.
I'm reading a lot of terns, DDD, TDD etc.
To recommend the books "Clean Code" and "Refactoring to Patterns" because they are very good.

In the end, this led me to pick up some prototypes of game that I had implemented on time and try to redo with OOP applied correctly since when I did, just follow my intuition (not studied anything).

Trying to implement a Finite State Machine for these games I came across several problems.

```
public class StateMachine
{
    private IState _globalState;
    private IState _currentState;
    private readonly List<IState> _previousStates;

   public StateMachine(IState globalState, IState currentState)
    {
       _globalState = globalState;
       _currentState = currentState;
       _previousStates = new List<IState>();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        if (_globalState != null)
            _globalState.Update();
        if (_currentState != null)
            _currentState.Update();
    }

    public void ChangeState(IState state)
    {
        _previousStates.Add(_currentState);
        _currentState.Exit();
        _currentState = state;
        _currentState.Enter();
    }

    public void BackToPreviousStates()
    {
        _currentState.Exit();
        _currentState = _previousStates[_previousStates.Count-1];
        _previousStates.Remove(_currentState);
        _currentState.Enter();
    }

    public void SetCurrentState(IState state)
    {
        _currentState = state;
    }

    public void SetGlobalState(IState state)
    {
        _globalState = state;
    }
}
```

Unlike some examples of the internet, I do not step on the player calling the Update method of the State, nor in Prora StateMachine as the example of ViniGodoy (http://sofiaia.wordpress.com/2008/07/11 and ... -states /) because I could not understand why.

is an example of a State

```
public class RunAway : TargetState
{
    public RunAway(IEntity entity, IEntity target)
        : base(entity, target)
    {
    }

    public override void Exit()
    {
      //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Enter()
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        if (Target.X > Entity.X)
        {
            Entity.Move(Key.Down);
        }


        Entity.StateMachine.BackToPreviousStates();

    }
}
```

My first doubts regarding the line and just Entity.StateMachine.BackToPreviousStates (), as this is against the patterns of OOP, I am enclosing a StateMachine of my Entity (a Player or Enemy).

Another problem is that in some cases I would

```
public override void Update()
    {
        var enemy;
            foreach (IEntity entity in Entity.World.Entities){

            if(entity .GetType() == typeOf(Enemy))
{
          enemy =(Enemy) entity;
             break;
 }
  }

   if (enemy  != null)
        Entity.StateMachine.SetCurrentState(new RunAway(Entity, enemy));

    }
```

I'm violating several tunnels, the State receives an Entity class in the constructor and handles World (the main class of the game that the Entity also receives in its constructor) and StateMachine, and I'm still instantiating a new State rather than usal as recommended in Singleton pattern (http://www.ai-junkie.com/books/toc_pgaibe.html).
States I'm not using Static, because I do not see how to apply as various states need not only information a player or StateMachine but a specific context (such as Runaway State who needs an enemy to which he'll run away).

I wanted the opinion of how to improve this implementation and does not violate encapsulation....

[edit]

for clarity

```
public abstract class State : IState
{
    private readonly IEntity _entity;

    protected IEntity Entity
    {
        get { return _entity; }
    }

    protected State(IEntity entidade)
    {
        _entity = entidade;
    }

    public abstract void Exit();
    public abstract void Enter();
    public abstract void Update();
}


public class Sleep: State
{
    private int _time;

    public Sleep(IEntity entidade) : base(entidade)
    {
    }

    public override void Exit()
    {
       // _time = 0;
    }

    public override void Enter()
    {

        _time = 0;
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        _time++;

        if (_time == 20)
            Entity.StateMachine.ChangeState(new Awake()); //<-- My Questions: Singletons ou instance?
                                                         //      how to enclosing it? using Entity.ChangeState(new Awake()) ?


    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be of the opinion that OO is good in of itself. OO is good because it lowers the costs of designing, building and maintaining complex software where many different components are built by different teams at different times and have to work together. If that is not the situation you're in, why do you want to rewrite working code in a "more OO" style? Is this just a learning exercise, or do you actually have a business case for spending time and effort making unnecessary changes?

Comment: I really long to work with games, then how much more professional code, the better

Comment: @FernandoMondo: You should reduce the problem you are having.  Also, suggestions are not generally a good fit for questions here.  You should aim to expose specific problems in your code, and then ask about those.

Answer (score 5):

It's really hard to say how to rewrite your FSM code in a more "OO" style because it doesn't appear to be what I would think of as a Finite State Machine in the first place. A Finite State Machine has the following structure:

```
sealed class Machine
{
    public readonly static State StartState = whatever;
    public State CurrentState { get; private set; }
    public Machine()
    {
        CurrentState = StartState;
    }
    public void ApplyNextInput(Input input)
    {
        CurrentState = ApplyPolicy(CurrentState, input);
    }
    private static State ApplyPolicy(State state, Input input)
    {
        // compute the new state based on the old state and the current input
    }
}
```

I have no idea what you are doing with this cache of previous states and all this logic for taking actions and whatnot. A FSM is extremely simple; there are a finite number of states, there are a finite number of inputs, and each input results in a new state based on a simple rule about how to transition from one state to another.

Comment: if you can look at this link http://www.ai-junkie.com/architecture/state_driven/tut_state1.html.  and sorry my bad english...

Answer (score 0):

This code is hard to understand because you do not show the definition of `StateMachine` class or `TargetState` class.  Nor do you give any idea what you are actually trying to do.

Mathematically a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) can be implemented as simply as a static enum singleton.

Clearly you want to do more than that... what exactly are you trying to do?

(My guess is you are implementing an [actor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model))

Comment: TargetState  saves only Target and Entity on properties to avoid repetition